# Android Google Maps Api - Possible to show online created maps?

Tags: android, api, google-maps, android-maps-v2

im currently developing with a friend a small app. We made some few custom maps on google.
If you dont know what i mean with "custom maps", its the maps you can create on google like "my friends"-map and mark all your friends on that map. Also you could mark some cool places on your custom "cool places"-map.

Yea and I wanted to know now, how i can load those custom maps in my own app?
Already made a small app with a GoogleMap on it, but cant find a way to show my selfmade maps.

Do I really have to draw all the markers etc. by code?

Thanks,
Termi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple to get custom Maps using Google API

Step1: Build a valid URL request with all necessary specifications.

Step2: Initiate the request and call Google API with this URL.

Step3: Remember you can play around and markers and other necessary customizations
       in the URL itself.

Step4: Google API returns you an Image object as response to your object of type "Image".

Step5: Store this image using a reference....& use it as and when required.

Step6: Use this image object and load it into your map using display methods available on
       Android.

Comment: Wow, didnt expect it to be so complicated. Just thought i could tell the GoogleMap to use my custom map with the id xxx. Anyway, thank you :). Really helpfull post!